# Tableau - Calculated Field : repeat count when multiple conditions are met

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api, calculated-field

This is a column

```
Status  Count
A B C   1000
A B     500
B D     200
C D     100
```

I have a column named Status where each row contains all the different status taken by a person.

I'm trying to create a calculated field which should give the following table

```
Status|  Status A|  Status B|  Status C|  Status D|
A B C |      1000|      1000|      1000|         0|
A B   |       500|       500|         0|         0|
B D   |         0|       200|         0|       200|
C D   |         0|         0|       100|       100|
```

Here's an attempt

```
IIF(CONTAINS([Status],"A"),"Status A",
    IIF(CONTAINS([Status],"B"),"Status B",
        IIF(CONTAINS([Status],"C"),"Status C",
             IIF(CONTAINS([Status],"D"),"Status D","")))
```

The returned result using the calculated field above is however:

```
Status|  Status A|  Status B|  Status C|  Status D|
A B C |      1000|         0|         0|         0|
A B   |       500|         0|         0|         0|
B D   |         0|       200|         0|         0|
C D   |         0|         0|       100|         0|
```

Can someone help me out with this?
I truly believe the solution would be simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right. So you want to display three different values in one column? What is the ambition for that? If you are able to represent one status in one column, your life gets much easier... For example

```
Status A | Status B | Status C
------------------------------
    X          X
                         X
    X                    X
  ...        ...       ...
```

Behind every column you set the specific counter.
I hope you can work with this.

Comment: hi @chaeschuechli, sorry I've edited the question and hopefully it's much clearer.